# Passing secure cookies to PHP via AJAX

Tags: php, cookies, oauth-2.0

I am implementing the LinkedIn [JavaScript to REST token exchange](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens), and have an SSL-enabled page that a member signs in on, which stores their oauth token in a secure 'credential' cookie, per the docs. I am then attempting to pass those cookies to a PHP page via jQuery `$.post()`:

```
$.post('https://' + document.domain + '/exchange.php', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

When I inspect the data being sent via Firebug, I can see the following in the header of the jQuery POST:

```
Cookie: __utma=xxxx; __utmc=xxxx; __utmz=xxxx; linkedin_oauth_YYYY=yyyy; PHPSESSID=xxxx; __utmb=xxxx
```

Yet on the exchange.php page, only the non-secure cookies are exposed (only the Google Analytics and the PHP session cookie can be seen by the receiving page) by doing `print_r($_COOKIE);`:

```
Array
(
  [__utma] => xxxx
  [__utmc] => xxxx
  [__utmz] => xxxx
  [PHPSESSID] => xxxx
  [__utmb] => xxxx
)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am POSTing to the same domain, using SSL, yet the secure cookie is not available to the `exchange.php` script.

Update:

I am now echoing out the $_SERVER values on the exchange.php page as well, and interestingly I get the following:

```
Array
(
  [HTTPS] => on
  [HTTP_COOKIE] => __utma=xxxx; __utmc=xxxx; __utmz=xxxx; linkedin_oauth_YYYY=yyyy; PHPSESSID=xxxx; __utmb=xxxx
)
```

So the cookie is getting passed, but not set in the $_COOKIE variable? FYI, running PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out - on the server that I am running the above code, I have [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/index.html) installed and it was limiting both request and cookie indices to a max length of 64 characters - which the full un-obsfuscated linkedin_oauth_YYYY cookie index was longer than. Here are the changes I made to php.ini:

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.cookie.max_array_index_length = 256
suhosin.cookie.max_name_length = 1024
suhosin.cookie.max_totalname_length = 4096
suhosin.request.max_totalname_length = 4096
suhosin.request.max_varname_length = 1024
```